Measure Theory Problem from Durrett PTE problem 1.3.9 (5th edition)
Question: Prove that Y is $\sigma(X)$ measurable if and only if Y=f(X) in which f is a measurable function from R to R.
My proposed proof: If $Y=f(X)$ and $f$ measurable, then $Y^{-1}(B)=\{w:X(w)\in f^{-1}(B)\}$ which proves the "if".
For only if, first of all I want to check that Y is a function of X. To do this, if $X(w_1)=X(w_2)$, then assuming that $Y(w_1)\neq Y(w_2)$ then pick any Borel set B such that $Y(w_1)\in B$ and $Y(w_2)\notin B$. Since $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable, $\{Y(w)\in B\}=\{X(w)\in B'\}$ for some Borel set B'. And a contradiction will be reached by asking if $X(w_1)=X(w_2)\in B'$. Furthermore, let $\{Y(w)=\alpha\}=
\{X(w)\in B_{\alpha}\}$, it is easy to check that the class $B_{\alpha}$ is a partition of R. Therefore, a function f can be defined to map any element of $B_{\alpha}$ to $\alpha$. Therefore, Y=f(X) for some f.
The rest is to prove that f is measurable, according to the hint of 1.3.9, we can define $Y_n(w)=\sum_{\alpha\in Z}\frac{\alpha}{2^n}I\{Y(w)\in [\frac{\alpha}{2^{n}},\frac{\alpha+1}{2^n})\}=\sum_{\alpha\in Z}\frac{\alpha}{2^n}I\{X(w)\in B_{\alpha,n}\}$. We have established that $Y$ is a function f of $X$, therefore, since $Y_n\rightarrow Y$, $f[X(w)]=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{\alpha\in Z}\frac{\alpha}{2^n}I\{X(w)\in B_{\alpha,n}\}$. We can therefore write $f(r)=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{\alpha\in Z}\frac{\alpha}{2^n}I\{B_{\alpha,n}(r)\}$.
And am I done since measurability is closed under sums and limits? My hesitation is that r is only defined at the range of $X(w)$. I can define, say, $f(r)=\infty$ for points outside of range of $X(w)$, but this will only work if $f^{-1}(\infty)$ or the range of $X(w)$ is Borel.
I know it for a fact that the image of a Borel measurable function isn't necessarily Borel. But intuitively, it really shouldn't matter since the definition of $Y$ does not change no matter how I define $f$ outside the image of $X$.
I guess that I overthought the problem...Anyone can help? Thank you so much!
